# What Are LAN technologies?

Tags: ethernet, lan

I know about different LAN topologies(like star, bus, ring,...) and that Ethernet is one of the ways to practically implement wired LANs. I wonder what other technologies exist to make LANs? And, is it possible to implement all the topologies with Ethernet?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: So much homework...

Comment: If you look into the 1980s many companies had their own technology. Acorn used ECONET for example... So there are a lot of technologies that can be used to create a LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, the most common technology for LANs beside Ethernet is Wi-Fi (IEEE 802.11). For home use there's also some power-line, everything else is practically extinct.

You can build practically any topology using Ethernet. Simple networks are a star, slightly larger form a tree, and large networks often combine multiple topologies like rings and meshes, using redundancy protocols like spanning tree, shortest path bridging, and TRILL. In particular, check out Cisco's [Spine-and-Leaf approach](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/nexus-7000-series-switches/white-paper-c11-737022.pdf).

While the very first Ethernet variants used an electrical bus, more modern variants use point-to-point links almost exclusively. These links are interconnected by switches which (more or less) form a logical bus - a node just sends a frame out through its network interface and the data arrives at the desired destination a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

I know about different LAN typologies(like star, bus, ring,...) and that Ethernet is one of the ways to practically implement wired LANs.

this is such a huge topic.visit https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Local-Area-Network-(LAN) get some idea about this.

I wonder what other technologies exist to make LANs?

A LAN, or a local area network, is a bit like the internet only a lot, lot smaller. That is, it only consists of a few devices that are all connected to each other. You may want a LAN so you can share files, send pictures and music to other computers, connect to a printer easily, or have a good old fashioned LAN party to play games with some pals.

you have to know network devices,cables and network models to make network.

is it possible to implement all the typologies with Ethernet?

yes,now a day ether-net mainly use for make every LAN topology